# Change CSS of current page title (in navigation menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so here is my problem:

I am making this Tumblr theme, so I can only have one html, which means I can't use the typical method of adding an id to each body. So I thought about it and concluded that I need 5 javascript codes that each checks the url on which I am currently and if I am f.ex. on http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com the `li` `#home` will have `border-bottom: #6DC176 solid 3px;` , `color: #6DC176;` and `font-weight: bold;`

Basically I have it all thought out, but I don't know a way to check if url = sth .

Here's the temporary link to the page if it helps you visualize what I want:
http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com

Comment: you can use javascript, `window.location.href`

Comment: And what is your (minimal/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) HTML?

Comment: @Syahrul So, with this I could do
$(document).ready(function () {
       if (window.location.href == "http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com") { $("#home").css("border-bottom", "#6DC176 solid 3px" "color", "#6DC176" "font-weight", "bold");
)};